# React Testing Library: Test if Elements have been mapped/rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

**Issue:**

I have a list of Items that I want to test by each one of the items `name` value (string). I'm using `@testing-library/react` and have the test suite correctly working, but I can't get my test to work.

**Overview:**

- Each `item` has a test id of `data-testid="side-menu-link"`. Does this have to be unique or can it be tested as is?
- The menuItems consist of strings like `Dashboard`, `Settings`, and `User Preferences`

**DisplayItems.test.tsx:**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

// Imports: App
import App from '../../App';

// Side Menu: Dashboard
test('Renders Dashboard correctly', () => {
  // Render: App
  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);

  // Expect
  expect(getByTestId('side-menu-link')).toHaveAttribute('Dashboard')
});


// Side Menu: User Preferences
test('Renders Dashboard correctly', () => {
  // Render: App
  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);

  // Expect
  expect(getByTestId('side-menu-link')).toHaveAttribute('User Preferences')
});
```

**Map Items:**

```
// Map Menu Items
return menuItems.map((menuItem, i) => {
  return (
    <Link data-testid="side-menu-link" key={i} href="#" className="side-menu-link" to={`/${menuItem.itemName}`}>
      <div className={props.currenttab === `${menuItem.itemName}` ? 'side-menu-item-container-selected-light' : 'side-menu-item-container-light'}>
        {menuItem.itemIcon}
        <p className={props.currenttab === `${menuItem.itemName}` ? 'side-menu-title-selected-light' : 'side-menu-title-light'}>{menuItem.itemName}</p>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
});
```

Comment: Can you expand on "I can't get my test to work"? What exactly is not working? What error message are you seeing (if any)?

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple `testID`s. Otherwise, there wouldn't be `__AllByTestId` selectors. The name wasn't well-thought out, it seems, because of similarity to HTML ids which must be unique.

A throw happens if you use `__ByTestId` yet you have multiple elements with the matching test id:

```js
it("getByTestId will throw with multiple testIDs", () => {
  const {getAllByTestId, getByTestId} = render(
    <View>
      <Text testID="foo">a</Text>
      <Text testID="foo">b</Text>
    </View>
  );
  expect(getAllByTestId("foo")).toHaveLength(2); // OK
  getByTestId("foo"); // => Error: Found multiple elements with testID: foo
});
```

To test a map, you can add test ids to the children and use the above pattern.

React Native:

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect";

// ...

it("should find text content in all children", () => {
  const {getAllByTestId} = render(
    <View>
      {[..."abcd"].map((e, i) => 
        <View key={e + i} testID="foo"><Text>{e}</Text></View>
      )}
    </View>
  );

  expect(getAllByTestId("foo")).toHaveLength(4);
  
  [..."abcd"].forEach((e, i) => {
    expect(getAllByTestId("foo")[i]).toHaveTextContent(e);
  });
});
```

React:

```js
it("should find text content in all children", () => {
  const {getAllByTestId} = render(
    <ul>
      {[..."abcd"].map((e, i) => 
        <li key={e + i} data-testid="foo">{e}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );

  expect(getAllByTestId("foo")).toHaveLength(4);

  [..."abcd"].forEach((e, i) => {
    expect(getAllByTestId("foo")[i].textContent).toEqual(e);
  });

  // or:
  //const contents = getAllByTestId("foo").map(e => e.textContent);
  //expect(contents).toEqual([..."abcd"]);
});
```

It's also possible to add a `testID` to the parent of the mapped list elements, select the parent, then traverse over its `.children` array to make assertions on each child tree.

Note the differences between `testID` in RN and `data-testid` in React.

---

As a side note, I'm not sure

```js
expect(getByTestId('side-menu-link')).toHaveAttribute('User Preferences')
```

makes much sense here. attributes are `<div this_is_an_attribute="foo">` -- you're probably looking for text content.

---

Packages used, for reference:

#### React Native

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.64.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.15.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.65.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

#### React

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.10.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.10.4",
    "@testing-library/dom": "7.21.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "10.4.7",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "3.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "12.0.11",
    "babel-jest": "26.1.0",
    "jest": "26.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "26.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Each `item` has a test id of `data-testid="side-menu-link"`. Does this have to be unique or can it be tested as is?

The test id has to be unique. I see you are using `getByTestId`. According to [the documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#getby), "`getBy*` queries return the first matching node for a query, **and throw an error** if no elements match or **if more than one match is found**." So your code would throw an error (assuming the list contained more than a single element).

But even if RTL did not throw an error, it makes sense that the test ids should be unique. Otherwise, how would you differentiate between two different elements in your test?

If for some reason you still want the test id to be the same, you will need to use a different query, such as `getAllBy*`, `queryBy*`, or `queryAllBy*`. Again, see [the documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries) for more information.