# How to cover onPress for touchableOpacity in .map loop jest testing library

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I'm trying to write test cases in React Native using Jest and Testing Library. I have a `.map` function where it renders a component with `TouchableOpacity`.

```js
{data.map((item, index) => (
    <SafeAreaView key={index}>
        <ItemView data={item} index={index} />
        {index >= data.length - 1 ? (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 16 }} />
        ) : (
            <View style={styles.itmSeperator} />
        )}
    </SafeAreaView>
))}
```

The ItemView looks like

```js
const ItemView = ({ data, index }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        testID="TouchablePress"
        onPress={() => onPress(data)}
        style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            paddingVertical: 16,
        }}
    >
        <Text style={styles.text}>{data.name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

For the above if I call
`fireEvent(getByTestId("TouchablePress"), "press");`  in tests file the test is getting file stating found multiple component with same id "TouchablePress".

Any suggestions on how to cover this test without getting failed?

Comment: You can retrieve them all using `getAllByTestId` then select the first one to actually fire the `press` action on. _OR_ have the `testID`s different for each `ItemView` based off their `index` value, then select the desired one.

Comment: @Saikiran see [React Testing Library: Test if Elements have been mapped/rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68201001/6243352). The touchable opacity isn't critical here, it's using `getAllByTestId` as shown in the link and as Julio describes above.